# UnsupportedClassVersionError while using Processing from the command line

Tags: java, matlab, command-line, command-line-interface, processing

I am trying to run a Processing command from the command-line through MATLAB. I am using a processing-java command to run the Processing command. When I run the command straight from the command-line, it works just as intended. When I use MATLAB to run the command through the command-line, I get the following error:

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: processing/mode/java/Commander : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I am confused because the command works straight from the command-line, but not through MATLAB. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you doing that requires you to run Processing from matlab?

Answer (score 1):

The version of Java installed with MatLab looks to be different than the JDK that you compiled your class with. Determine the path to the JRE that was installed with the JDK you use and set the `MATLAB_JAVA` environment variable appropriately.